# How do I delay a yii2-queue task until all previous tasks are complete?

Tags: yii2

I am working on a Yii2 project that uses yii2-queue to process a large job in smaller steps. The final step in the queue "finalizes" the job. It's working fine with a single process. Now I want to scale it up to 8 processes, but I'm concerned the final step will begin running before all of the incremental steps are 100% complete.

Does yii2-queue have a built-in feature for guaranteeing the processing order of the steps? For example, does the priority value guarantee that all tasks of a specific priority will be completed before processing tasks of the next priority? I could handle this manually with a lock file, but I'm wondering if that's unnecessary.

Comment: havent used it before but from Docs **you can also specify a priority when pushing a job. Jobs with a lower priority will be executed first. The default priority is `1024`** but i am not sure it guarantees that the job started before is finished or not, but it is worth a try maybe it triggers the next job once the first one is finished

Comment: I've been studying [the code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/src/drivers/db/Queue.php#L189), and it appears the priority value is just for sorting the jobs. I see nothing that limits the highest priority to less than the lowest incomplete job. But I think that's all it would take to implement it.

Comment: Modifying the yii2 library isn't really an option on this project, so I'll probably just use a lock file that is specific to the job implementation. If anyone has a better idea, please share it.

Comment: cant you create your custom logic using [job-status](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/usage.md#job-status)

Comment: Possibly. But the worker, which doesn't know the ID of the other workers, is where the check will have to occur. The controller just sets up the jobs and is done, so I think a direct query to the job queue from the worker might be easier. Thanks.